# Where is the libraries folder in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile-development

I am getting an error 'linker command failed with exit code 1' when I try to build my mobile app in Xcode for the iPhone.  In looking up solutions to fix this I came across this advice:

"the suprojects should be removed, which is everything under Libraries inside Xcode."

(solution found here)  https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/3

But I cannot find an Xcode folder on mac that contains a Libraries folder within it.  Does anyone know where this is located at??

Comment: Probably it's referring to a “Libraries” group in your project outline. But it would be helpful if you gave us a link to the solution you're trying to use.

Or you could describe the linker problem you're having in more detail (e.g. by copying the relevant part of your build log and pasting it into your question) and maybe we can help you solve it directly.

Comment: Ok I just added a link to the solution I found online.  Do you know where the "Libraries" group would be??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open your project in Xcode.
2. From the menu bar, choose View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator.
3. The left sidebar of the Xcode window now shows the Project Navigator.
4. At the bottom of the left sidebar, in the “Filter” box, type “Libraries”.
5. If, in the Project Navigator, you now see a yellow folder icon with the word “Libraries” next to it, then you have found the Libraries folder you are looking for.
6. If there is no Libraries folder, then the solution you're trying to use is not the correct solution for your problem.